# get facebook graph user from Respone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook 3.0 sdk so sorry in advance. My problem is this:
I am trying to get user id, in order to do so I found out that I need to do this:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, null);
Response response = Request.executeAndWait(request);
```

from here I am stacked, I don't know how to get the Id of the user from the response.

Maybe there is some Way to request the `GraphUser`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), you can use http request on

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=replace-this-by-your-access-token

to get the id of the logged in user

Comment: He could also get the id with (String) graphObject.getProperty("id"), but I think he want to use the higher level call GraphUser

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Request request = new Request(session, "me", null, HttpMethod.GET);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
if (response.getError() != null) {
   // bla bla 
} else {
   GraphUser graphUser = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphUser.class);
}
```